# Better ways to parse the Content-Length from the HTTP header

Tags: c, strings, parsing, http

I have a buffer that contains the HTTP header, which contains the `Content-Length` string indicating how big the file is that needs to be downloaded.

I am looking to write a generic function for parsing a substring and eventually a value that needs to be converted to an `int` from a string.

The following approach seems to work but seems more like a "brute-force" approach. Any better ideas?

```c
void parse(char *src, char *dst, const char *firstKey, const char *secKey)
{
    char *start = strstr(src, firstKey) + 2;
    char *end = strstr(start, secKey);
    size_t bytes = end - start;
   
    memcpy(dst, start, bytes);  
}

int main()
{
    char httpHeader[] = {72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 32, 50, 48, 49, 32, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 100, 13, 10, 68, 97, 116, 101, 58, 32, 77, 111, 110, 44, 32, 49, 55, 32, 74, 97, 110, 32, 50, 48, 50, 50, 32, 50, 49, 58, 53, 56, 58, 52, 51, 32, 71, 77, 84, 13, 10, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 58, 32, 65, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 47, 50, 46, 52, 46, 50, 57, 32, 40, 85, 98, 117, 110, 116, 117, 41, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 48, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 104, 116, 109, 108, 13, 10, 13, 10};   
    
    /*
    what httpHeader above stores:
    HTTP/1.1 201 Created
    Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2022 21:58:43 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html
    */
    
    char dst[100] = {0};
    parse(httpHeader, dst, "Content-Length", "\n");    // dst => Content-Length: 0
    
    char dst1[100] = {0};    
    parse(dst, dst1, ":", "\r");
    
    // get the int value
    int contentLenVal = atoi(dst1);

    printf ("dst: %s\ndst1: %s\n\nContent value: %d\n", dst, dst1, contentLenVal);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any better ideas?

**Consume the buffer**

Rather than leave the buffer "as-is" while parsing,  adjust its start and end while parsing.

```
char *s = httpHeader;
s = parse(s, "Content-Length", "\n");
if (s == NULL) Handle_Error();
s = parse(s, ":", "\r");
if (s == NULL) Handle_Error();
long contentLenVal = strtol(s, ...);   // See below  for details.
```

---

Avoid bugs.

**Avoid going off the end**

Below may + 2 past the end of the string.  Better to walk carefully.

```
// char *start = strstr(src, firstKey) + 2;
char *start = strstr(src, firstKey);
if (start == NULL || start[0] == '\0' || start[1] == '\0') {
  Handle_Error();
}
start += 2;
....
if (end == NULL) {
  Handle_Error();
}
```

IAC, the `+ 2` is strange.  I'd expect:

```
char *start = strstr(src, firstKey);
if (start == NULL) {
  Handle_Error();
}
start += strlen(firstKey);
```

**`dst` lacks a certain *null character***

Presently code relies on the caller to pre-fill with `'\0`.  Better to pass in buffer size and append a `'\0'` explicitly in the function.

```
// void parse(char *src, char *dst, ...
void parse(const char *src, size_t sz, char *dst, ...

  ...
  ptrdiff_t diff = end - start;
  if (diff > sz) {
    Handle_Error();
  } else {
    size_t bytes = (size_t) diff;
    memcpy(dst, start, bytes);
    dest[bytes] = '\0';
  }
```

**Use `strtol()`**

Robust code looks for errors,

```
// int contentLenVal = atoi(dst1);
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
long contentLenVal = strtol(dst1, &endptr, 10);
if (dst1 == endptr || errno || contentLenVal < LEN_MIN || contentLenVal >  LEN_MAX) {
  Handle_Error();
}
```

**Minor: Use `const`**

```
// void parse(char *src, char *dst, ...
void parse(const char *src, char *dst, ...
```

If code is to consume `src`, leave as is.

**Minor: Wrap**

```
// char httpHeader[] = {72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 32, 50, 48, 49, 32, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 100, 13, 10, 68, 97, 116, 101, 58, 32, 77, 111, 110, 44, 32, 49, 55, 32, 74, 97, 110, 32, 50, 48, 50, 50, 32, 50, 49, 58, 53, 56, 58, 52, 51, 32, 71, 77, 84, 13, 10, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 58, 32, 65, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 47, 50, 46, 52, 46, 50, 57, 32, 40, 85, 98, 117, 110, 116, 117, 41, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 48, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 104, 116, 109, 108, 13, 10, 13, 10};
```

Versus

```
char httpHeader[] = {72, 84, 84, 80, 47, 49, 46, 49, 32, 50, 48, 49, 32, 67,
    114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 100, 13, 10, 68, 97, 116, 101, 58, 32, 77, 111, 110,
    44, 32, 49, 55, 32, 74, 97, 110, 32, 50, 48, 50, 50, 32, 50, 49, 58, 53, 56,
    58, 52, 51, 32, 71, 77, 84, 13, 10, 83, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 58, 32, 65,
    112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 47, 50, 46, 52, 46, 50, 57, 32, 40, 85, 98, 117, 110,
    116, 117, 41, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 76, 101, 110,
    103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 48, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84,
    121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 47, 104, 116, 109, 108, 13, 10,
    13, 10};
```

Tip: Use an auto-formatter.

Comment: thanks! why is it better for the callee to take care of null terminator as opposed to the caller making sure the buffer is null terminated?

Comment: @xyf Callee know where to efficiently write it and less repeated code.  Consider a buffer of 1,000s of bytes.  Should the caller be obliged to pre-zeros thousands or let the callee set the one?

Comment: so perhaps just memset the entire buffer to 0 inside the caller? for which the caller would need to pass the size of the buffer too

Comment: @xyf The caller should pass the size anyways.  Further, say user passed a buffer pointer size to  100,000 bytes yet the function only needs to set a few bytes and then a _null character_.  There is no advantage yet weaknesses to pre memset-ing an arbitrary sized buffer by the caller or callee.

Comment: yeah. I reckon if the entire buffer isn't guaranteed to filled up with legit values, and if a buffer is quite large, it's a safer bet to not memset and rather append `\0` at the end after populating